# how register via java config a listener without StepExecutionListener implementation neither StepListenerExecutionSupport extending

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I am studding Spring Batch in Action book and I found StopListener example in page 114/115. How can I register a listener class which doesn't implement StepExecutionListener neither extend StepListenerExecutionSupport? I am not using Spring Xml configuration so I have to convert the example provided in xml to java configuration.

According to the book

```
public class StopListener {
  private StepExecution stepExecution;
  @BeforeStep
  public void beforeStep(
      StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }
 @AfterRead
  public void afterRead() {
    if(stopConditionsMet()) {
      stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
    }
  }...

<bean id="stopListener" class="com.manning.sbia.ch04.stop.StopListener" /> 
<batch:job id="importProductsJob">
  <batch:step id="importProductsStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
      <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
      <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="stopListener" />
      </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

As I tried:

```
...
       @Bean
       public StepExecutionListener stepListener(){
              return new StopListener(); //obviously, it raises casting issues
       }

       @Bean
       public Step stepA(ItemReader<String> readerA, ItemWriter<String> writerA,
                     StepExecutionListener stepListener) {  
              return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA").<String, String> chunk(1)
                           .reader(readerA).writer(writerA).allowStartIfComplete(false)
                           .startLimit(1).listener(stepListener).build();
       }

@Component
public class StopListener {
       private StepExecution stepExecution;
       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StopListener.class);

       @BeforeStep
       public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
              log.info("StopListener.beforeStep()");
              this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
       }

       @AfterRead
       public void afterRead() {
              if (true) {
                     stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Just return `StopListener` instead of `StepExecutionListener` and inject that tinto the method or simply call `stepListener` from your `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

@Bean
       public StopListener stepListener(){
              return new StopListener(); //obviously, it raises casting issues
       }

```
   @Bean
   public Step stepA(ItemReader<String> readerA, ItemWriter<String> writerA) {  
          return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA").<String, String> chunk(1)
                       .reader(readerA).writer(writerA).allowStartIfComplete(false)
                       .startLimit(1).listener(stepListener()).build();
   }
```

the `listener` method takes an `Object` and it detects either the type or annotated methods.